# Ways to resources in PHP

Tags: php, path

I try to resolve my problem with resource path in Php. In file `header.php` I include scripts and stylesheets, but when I `require_once('../templates/header.php');` in file `login.php` from `views` directory I get 404 error code on all my resources, because all files must be in subdirectory of  `views` direcroty. How I can solve this problem?

Path:

`/var/www/reg/templates/header.php` - path to header

`/var/www/reg/views/login.php` - path to login

`/var/www/reg/js/script.js` - path to js
`/var/www/reg/css/style.css` - path to css

Comment: Can you post your file directories?

Comment: Can you please write down the paths for the header, the login and the resources?

Comment: I added pathes) Please help)

Comment: what is the url you use? I think you url should be something like: `domain.com/reg/views/login.php`

Comment: localhost/reg/views/login.php

Comment: Check your browser's view source. What url you get for your resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your file structure

inside header.php

try this way:

```
<link href="/reg/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/reg/js/script.js" ></script>
```

As I have tested it works for me.

Comment: yes it works! but it works only in `views/login.php` and neither in `index.php` or somwhere else

Comment: I have made changes now try it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd probably do it, not sure if best practice, but similar to the way wordpress works, IE

In your a index file (in the `reg/` dir or in a config file if you have one):

```
define('SITEPATH', dirname(__FILE__).'/');
```

Then you can require files like this:

```
require_once(SITEPATH . 'templates/header.php');
```

Then when you're calling your resource files, you can do something similar this:

```
<script src="<?php echo SITEPATH; ?>js/script.js"></script>
```

But, imo, backend stuff shouldn't really be on template files, but because your directories are different to how I'd lay them out.

Comment: I already have tried to do like this but I didn't get any results. I have idea how I can do that but this crutch