# PHP include doen't work inside subfolders

Tags: php, html, css

In my project, I put my file inside this folder:

/test_server/

But, I make group for my css file inside /test_server/css

The problem is, I want to add new module for my project, called scheduler. It has many files so I create another folder for this module, called /test_server/scheduler.

I have header file contains all my navigation menu. Let's say this file called wrapper.php. this file use css from my /test_server/css/ folder

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-fit.css" />
```

wrapper.php located inside /test_server/
style-fit.css located inside /test_server/css/

Next, I have file scheduler.php inside /test_server/scheduler/ folder

I've tried using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] inside it like this,

```
$path2 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path2 .= "/test_server/wrapper.php";
include_once($path2);
```

It can contain the wrapper.php, but, the references for style-fit.css is missing.

How to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that you do not have the correct rights to access that sub-directory?

Comment: I think you are looking for this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034380/ways-to-resources-in-php/26035432#26035432

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola sorry, it doesn't work. I want to call the wrapper.php from my /test_server/scheduler/scheduler.php, where the wrapper.php located inside /test_server/. all the css located inside /test_server/css. did you mean I must recall all css again in my scheduler.php?

Comment: No no I just want you to check out my answer if it's helps you.

Comment: Have you the chance to post a little of code? Where are the not working includes. With your info, at the moment I cannot exclude the mistyping, for example, and solving all the actual case of misbehaving is far more demanding than copying a couple of lines of code (with a precise file path indication)

Comment: @Eineki I've edited my post to make it more precise. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this way?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/test_server/css/style-fit.css" />
```

This will work perfectly only if you are successfully able to include wrapper.php.

Comment: This will only work if the map `test_server` is located in the root

Comment: OP Says `It can contain the wrapper.php, but, the references for style-fit.css is missing.`

Comment: @asdf Please Upvote and accept my answer so it will helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
$path2 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path2 .= "test_server/wrapper.php";
include_once($path2);
```

Comment: Too many backslashes? Good point! Also try a simple `echo $path2;` before the `include_once();` to see whether the path is correct.

Comment: Also use require/require_once, instead of include. Since you are porgramming the chance you can pass over a failed inclusion is quite minimal.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work. If I delete the backslash, it'll go to C:/xampp/htdocstest_server/header-fit.php instead of C:/xampp/htdocs/test_server/header-fit.php

Comment: I have created same folder structure and its working fine in my machine.